# Order date from most recent down

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking to sort my info by the most recent date down as well as a cost amount from cheapest to more expensive. My date field is a timestamp in mysql that is defualted with current timestamp. I also have a "paymentamount" that I want to organize as well. This is what I have so far and its not working.

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM `Carriers` ORDER BY date,paymentamount DESC";
```

Answer (score 2):

If not specified, a column is sorted in ascending order by default. As you're sorting on two columns, you'll have to specify the direction for each.

In this case, try:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    Carriers
ORDER BY
    date DESC,
    paymentamount DESC
```

When you say "cheapest to more expensive", for the cost, it sounds like you actually want to sort the `paymentamount` in ascending order. The date, to be "most recent date down" will need to be in descending order though. In this case, you could use:

```
ORDER BY
    date DESC,
    paymentamount ASC
```

In your PHP code (for easy copy+paste):

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM `Carriers` ORDER BY date DESC, paymentamount ASC";
```

Answer (score 0):

The most recent date is DESC order, and cheapest price is asc order.

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM `Carriers` ORDER BY date DESC, paymentamount ASC";
```

Answer (score 0):

Query should be `$select = "SELECT * FROM Carriers ORDER BY date DESC, paymentamount ASC";`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to provide different orderings for your two fields.  It looks like you want your date in DESC, but your paymentamount in ASC.  So...

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM `Carriers` ORDER BY date DESC,paymentamount ASC";
```